# Updating WPF labels from static object

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have been trying to get this working all day. I am attempting to learn C# and writing a blackjack program. I have never worked with WPF before and everything about it is extremely confusing and frustrating.

I have three labels on my window that I am trying to update from a static instance of a viewmodel class (BlackjackViewModel):

```
<Label x:Name="lblPlayerTotal" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static classes:BlackjackViewModel.Instance}, Path=PlayerTotal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38"/>
<Label x:Name="lblDealerTotal" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static classes:BlackjackViewModel.Instance}, Path=DealerTotal, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<Label x:Name="lblCardsRemaining" Content="{Binding Source={x:Static classes:BlackjackViewModel.Instance}, Path=CardsRemaining, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="584,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I can't get anything to appear, the labels are just blank. According to the debugger BlackjackViewModel is sending PropertyChanged events but as far as I can tell nothing is listening. The viewmodel's properties all look like this:

```
    public int DealerTotal {
        get { return dealerTotal; } 
        set 
        {
            dealerTotal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DealerTotal");    
        }
    }
```

and a breakpoint at OnPropertyChanged will trigger when the viewmodel is updated so it's sending events.

I tried refactoring my code to make the BlackjackViewModel instance not static and that didn't help either. This was difficult because I have an EventListener set up that updates the viewmodel's count of remaining cards when a card is dealt from the deck so I had to comment it out. It still didn't work with the following XAML:

```
    <Label x:Name="lblPlayerTotal" DataContext="blackjackViewModel" Content="{Binding PlayerTotal}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="38"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblDealerTotal" DataContext="blackjackViewModel" Content="{Binding DealerTotal}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="lblCardsRemaining" DataContext="blackjackViewModel" Content="{Binding CardsRemaining}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="584,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

How do I actually have the labels update when the viewmodel instance updates?

update: With the corrected static singleton setup, the labels contain the number 0, not blank. Here is the ViewModel. When a property is updated, the debugger breaks on a breakpoint set in OnPropertyChanged. I get no binding errors in the Output view. I'll download a WPF tracer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BlackjackGame
{
    class BlackjackViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static BlackjackViewModel __instance = null;

        private int dealerTotal;
        private int playerTotal;
        private int cardsRemaining;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        static BlackjackViewModel()
        {
            __instance = new BlackjackViewModel();
        }

        public int CardsRemaining
        {
            get { return cardsRemaining; }
            set
            {
                cardsRemaining = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CardsRemaining");
            }
        }
        public int PlayerTotal
        {
            get { return playerTotal; }
            set
            {
                playerTotal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PlayerTotal");
            }
        }
        public int DealerTotal {
            get { return dealerTotal; } 
            set 
            {
                dealerTotal = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DealerTotal");    
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {      
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
              PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public static BlackjackViewModel Instance
        {
            get { return __instance; }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full code of your ViewModel. BTW, there is no such thing in .Net as an "EventListener". Please don't use java terminology, it causes me vomits and diarrhea.

Comment: Did you set the Control's `DataContext` to the instance of your ViewModel? When debugging WPF make sure you have your `Output` window up to see the binding errors. You may need to turn on `WPF tracing` in your options. Also if you still have issues you might want to install something like Snoop, a WPF binding debugger.

Comment: @Aron DataContext has nothing to do when you're binding to a static source via `{Binding Source={x:Static ...}}`

Comment: @HighCore see the latter half of the question where the OP switches to a non-static instance, without saying set the instance in the Control.

Comment: @Aron in the second part of the question the DataContext of these UI elements is explicitly set to the string `blackjackViewModel`, which of course, being a `System.String`, doesn't have `PlayerTotal` or any of those properties.

Comment: @HighCore Nice spot. Seems like the answer then.

Comment: @Aron I'm more interested in finding out why the static "singleton" like approach didn't work to begin with. I bet there's an issue with the ViewModel itself.

Comment: @HighCore "I can't get anything to appear, the labels are just blank" I suspect its a binding issue. I don't think it ever bound in the first place.

Comment: I added the Viewmodel.
Is EventListener Java terminology? I've never used Java, that's just what the function that listens for events is called.